# Create countdown timer with javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to make a script that will start a 4 hour countdown after a users action.

For example lets say that a user have the option to buy a weapon and then can buy again after 4 hours. So when the user will buy the weapon a 4 hour countdown will start and after the pass of 4 hours the user can buy a weapon again.

I have done a countdown script for specific day and hour but i don't know how to do this.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Do you want to show the timer, or just disable the action. If it is the second, check setInterval function in javascript.

Comment: http://www.rmkwebdesign.com/Countdown_Timers/Style_1_A.html
this is the site that i made the countdown for specific day and time.

Comment: I presume you want the time tracked properly even if they close their browser? So you'll need to persist that data some place - client or server-side?

Comment: yes i want the countdown timer to work with real time and not to start over and over again after refreshing page

Comment: @marouska If you store it locally, the user may be able to tamper with the data. Are you okay with that, or are you prepared to stand up a server-side solution?

Comment: the game is already online so i am prepared...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this would be the client side code

```
var buy = function( weaponID ){
    //Ajax call to buy.php
    //lets say you post one variable containing the id of the weapon
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'buy.php',
        data: "id="+weaponID,
        success: function(data){
            if(data==1) updateScreen()
            else alert("Please wait X more time")
        }
    })
}
```

Server side code

```
buy.php:

$weaponID = $_POST["id"];
$userID = $_SESSION["userID"];

$q = mysql_query("  SELECT  time,
                            weaponCount
                    FROM table
                    WHERE user = $userID
;");
$e = mysql_fetch_array($q);
list( $time, $wcount ) = $e;
$wcount++;  

$currTime = time();
$diff = $currTime - $time;
$hours = $diff / ( 60 * 60 );

if( $hours > 4 ){
    mysql_query("   UPDATE table
                    SET time = $currTime,
                        weaponCount = $wcount
                    WHERE user = $userID
    ;");
    echo 1;
}
else echo 0;
```